# Simple probability and sample space problem.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I was working on the following problem from my textbook:

> 3.2 An overseas shipment of 5 foreign automobiles contains 2 that have slight paint blemishes. If an agency receives 3 of these automobiles at random, list the elements of the sample space S, using the letters B and N for blemished and nonblemished, respectively; then to each sample point assign a value x of the random variable X representing the number of automobiles with paint blemishes purchased by the agency.

Here is my sample space:

N    B    B x = 2

B    N    B x = 2

N    N    B x = 1

B    B    N x = 2

N    B    N x = 1

B    N    N x = 1

N    N    N x = 0

The accompanying solution manual for the book has the following listed:

[image]

Question: isn't their answer wrong? I was under the impression that there are strictly $2$ automobiles with paint blemishes, so how is it possible for $BBB$ to be an element of the sample space?

Comment: Both answers are OK if you assign $0$ probability to their $BBB$. Why not? I could even insert the captains age. That would not be wrong but unnecessary. OK. Their $BBB$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @zoli How could you insert the captain's age? Isn't the sample space specifically concerning the outcomes of the paint quality and nothing else?

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to express that  a larger model (with $P(BBB)=0)$ will not result in wrong results. If I insert the captains age as an independent random variable (uniform over $(30,31,...60)$) then I don't destroy the model, I am just silly -- simply.

Comment: I see, alright. I think I got it. So hypothetically, let's say the company were purchasing $5$ cars instead of $3$. Then in theory, I could fill up the permutations all the way up to $BBBBB$, even though all events with $x > 2$ would never in fact occur (probability of $0$) and could therefore be omitted from the sample space, right?

Comment: Yes,   *********    Right!